# How to load Java Script in Web View in android for multiple windows?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In my project web view not supported for java scripting for loading multiple window(frames) web pages on single web page,but it runs for single page

Below is my web view code:-

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("myurl");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are try to use single web-url and your site may contain other site url or web pages within single page,..

You should enable javascript and multiple windows true

you have to change web view settings

try this,

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true); //suport multiple windows
```

Comment: yehhhh, let me know if anything else

Answer (score 0):

To enable Javascript in a WebView, I used this following code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("myURL");
```